# Permissions-Policy header

Tags: google-chrome

Сегодня начал ругаться в консоль с таким сообщением

```
Error with Permissions-Policy header: Origin trial controlled feature not enabled: 'browsing-topics'.
```

сейчас в header установлено это

```
Permissions-Policy "accelerometer=(),autoplay=(),camera=(),encrypted-media=(),fullscreen=*,geolocation=*,gyroscope=(),magnetometer=(),microphone=(),midi=(),sync-xhr=*,usb=(),xr-spatial-tracking=()"
```

удаление Permissions-Policy из header не помогает.

Answer (score 1):

Проблема решается выключением ublock.